# Loading Thymeleaf Template from Spring Cloud Config server

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-cloud-config, flying-saucer

Spring Boot Microservice project build using Thymeleaf and FLying Saucer that generates PDF from HTML templates. It is build using Thymeleaf and Flying Saucer. Currently, templates and images folders are under resources. I want to move those folders to Spring Cloud Config Server. Is there any way to do it?

Created spring server in cloud foundry and bind application. It does not have problem finding other application property file based on environment but it has problem finding template folder. Here is the error:

```
Error occurred during processing ","context":"default","exception":"org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "templates/Sample.html")
 org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:235)
 org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100)
 org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:649)
 org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098)
 org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1059)
 org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1048)
 org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
 org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746)
 org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
 org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:69)
 org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
```

Comment: There are probably many ways to do this. Try to specify a bit more. Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @GustavoPassini created spring server in cloud foundry and bind my application. It does not have problem finding other application property file based on environment but it has problem finding template folder. Here is the error: 
 
 

 "context":"default","exception":"org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: \"templates/sample.html\")\n\tat org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:235)